# Featured Tab Message Confusing

Tags: bug, tags, design

[image]

I was given the above explanation as to why I wasn't seeing any questions.  Initially I was looking for evidence as to being on the Featured tab, but because the tag I'd switched to had no Featured questions, it had no tab.  Therefore I couldn't clearly see which tab I needed to flick.  I suppose this is further compounded by the tabs no longer looking like typical tabs either.

I found this a bit confusing.  Maybe there should be a Featured tab present even if there are no Featured questions, or maybe the statement in orange at the bottom ('Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?'), should be a hyperlink and maybe offer the alternative of 'Viewing the newest questions'?

Comment: *"Initially I was looking for evidence as to being on the Featured tab"* - **You are on the Featured tab**. I guess the problem here is that SO 1. remembers which tab you were on last time you looked at tagged questions; and 2. doesn't show "Featured" if it's empty. So if you browse to a new tag where there aren't any, you get the result above. Not sure the feedback is unclear, though.

Comment: It was unclear enough for me to start looking for a highlighted tab called 'Featured'.  It confused me more that there wasn't one and it wasn't where I expected it to be.  I'm just saying that there's room for improvement, specifically for someone who's ventured into the 'Featured' tab for maybe the first time and then switched tags.

Comment: I think it's more of a design bug than a feature request, hence my retagging