# Unable to view the featured questions tab in stack overflow

Tags: discussion, featured-questions

Currently I am in Featured tag and doing search for `angular-ngmodel` then I am getting this below message

[image]

Then if I move to some other tag, then I can't see the `featured` tab option. 
[image]

So Is the tab is showing/hiding by depend on the records availability? I am not saying this is the bug. I just want to know this is `status by design`? or any reason there.

Comment: Are you talking about the "frequent" tab? I see no featured in any of your images?

Comment: @BDL.. OP is talking about featured..bounties. Though I dont see the point here

Comment: @BDL it is unclear again but compare the tabs for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=frequent&pageSize=50)  which have active bounties and then have a look at the screenshots again.

Comment: @rene: I'm confused because op talks about featured **tag**. And then shows a error message from frequent **tab**

Comment: @BDL We know this OP, right? And their capability to be extremely unclear about what they ask.At least in this case I kind of could figure out what they could have meant.

Comment: OOPS. Sorry I have put a wrong image. I have update that. and sorry for that typo issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Featured Tab Message Confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290429/featured-tab-message-confusing)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill not sure its a dupe.. it _does_ show a tab if you toggle tags when you happen to be on featured tab

Comment: @MichaelGaskill That's may be related with the question but not an answer.  I Am not sure. How did you the duplicate question without that question does not have any answer.

Answer (score 6):

> I just want to know this is status by design?

Yes. Featured tab shows up when there are any questions with bounty related to the tag you search else it does not show.I do not see why you need to show it

Example of an existing tag *without featured* is [observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/observable).

You can however still go to the message by manipulating url.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/observable?sort=featured

<s>***Secondly there is no tag as `Angular-model` right now.***</s>

Comment: Sorry I have update that tag `angular-ngmodel`